# Fixing the column width in ASP.NET gridview no matter what

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.NET GridView with square cells (width and height of GridView are the same and so is the number of columns and rows / no headers). Every cells contains a LinkButton (with sometimes a small Font Awesome icon).

When I load the GridView, the column width changes. How can I make sure that the column width stays fixed, even if the text (or small image) would be bigger than the cell?

I've had no success looking it up on google. Somehow everything I try ends up "inflating" the column anyways. It just needs to force the width to stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use TemplateField and directly set its ItemStyle width to the fixed value you want

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <%--<ItemStyle Width="80px" />--%><!--OR use this format-->
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" runat="server" CommandName="CellClick" Visible="false"/>                                                                             
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: How would I combine this with my ButtonField?  <asp:ButtonField CommandName="CellClick" Visible="false" /> I need that for hooking up with a clientside function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Oznov instead of ButtonField can you try use a button in the template? I've updated my answer.